# how to add uiview all over views

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

i have a tabbar app with 4 tabs.
i want to add a small view (frame is: 0, 390, 320, 50) just over the tabcontrollers. the view shows a picture (like banner).
but i want to see it on all over tabs. not just first tab's view controllers.
where should i add it? should i use viewcontroller for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added your UITabBarController to the window in your AppDelegate, that adding the new UIView as a subview of the window will do the trick

Comment: yes i add tabbar in appdelegate. [window addSubview:tabBarController.view]; bView=[[bottomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 390, 320, 50)];[window addSubview:bView]; but it doesnt display. i think first tab's view comes over it. no error no displaying bottomView just over tabbar.

Comment: sorry its my fault. its background is white, so it cant be seen. thanks.